# Is it possible for compression algorithms to generate identical output for two different files?

Tags: algorithm, compression, hash, unique

I would like to know if compression algorithms always generate unique output for two different sets of files.

Say, I have two files A and B, and say I am applying a compression algorithm (for instance like PKZIP - this could be any compression algorithm) for each of these files to get A.zip and B.zip respectively. Is it possible for A.zip to be exactly identical to B.zip at the binary level for some combination of A and B. If this is not possible, can we safely assume compression to be equivalent to cryptographic hashing when it comes to guaranteeing uniquenes? On the other hand if it is possible, could you please provide me a sample A and B file along with the compression algorithm to use to verify this duplicity?

Comment: Your mention of "cryptographic hashing" has prompted some people to think that you intend to use lossless compression for security purposes -- is that correct? If so, that's a terrible idea, for all the reasons they give. But if you are only interested in guaranteeing uniqueness, and are prepared to deal with the variable-length outputs compression gives you, then it may be a reasonable choice (although for all practical purposes, using a fixed-length cryptographic hash will be faster and work well -- the probability of key collision with e.g. 128-bit keys is beyond negligible).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Lossless compression (as used in ZIP files) will always produce different outputs for different files - otherwise you would be unable to reliably recover the original data. However, the output data may be of any size - and for some inputs, it will be larger than the original input. As such, this isn't usually very useful as a hash, which generally requires a fixed-size output.

Lossy compression (eg, MP3, JPEG, etc) can produce the same output for different inputs - as such, you cannot recover the original data, but instead get something similar to it. Because of this the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) isn't a problem, and so you can guarantee that it will reduce the output size, often even specifying the desired output size. However, because similar but slightly different inputs will often produce the same output, this isn't useful for hashing either, as hashing requires small changes in the input to produce large changes in the output.

Comment: +1 for pigeonhole principle because I'm a sucker for math. 

However, does this address the cryptographic hash question?

Comment: Sure. Lossless doesn't work because it's variable-size, lossy because small changes don't result in large hash changes (avalanche effect).

Comment: @bdonian what's the requirement on hashes to having fixed length?

Also, the idea of 'losing' information (ie lossy) doesn't stop an algorithm from being a good hash. MD5 or SHA-1 are lossy compression algorithms, are they not?

I think the important thing to note here is that all crypto hash functions are compression algorithms, but not the other way around. (Crypto hash functions must be "hard" to invert)

And, after saying that, I do note that this somewhat contradicts my answer below :P

Comment: I never said losing information prevents something from being a good hash. Indeed, any good hash loses ALL information (ie, you cannot recover any information about the original message at all). Also, generally hashes are smaller than the input message, which cannot be ensured with a lossless compression algorithm.

Answer (score 14):

It is not possible. If the compressed files were identical, how could they generate different results when you decompress them?

Comment: Clear and simple: +1. Note this applies for lossless compression only (which the OP suggests by talking about PKZIP, but doesn't explicitly mention).

Comment: When I wrote the answer I didn't even consider the possibility of lossy compression, due to the way the question was worded. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, lossy compression can give the same output as already noted.

But I think a very important point that hasn't been mentioned is that cryptographic hashes should be very hard to reverse (or to reproduce the same hash via two different inputs). For this reason lossless and hence reversible compression algorithms like zips would be unsuitable as a cryptographic hash.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the uselessness of compression as a security measure, but I think the OP was mainly interested in just using compressed outputs to guarantee uniqueness -- and guaranteeing uniqueness is something that lossless compression does *even better than* cryptographic hashes (though with the obvious downside of producing a variable-length output).

Answer (score 2):

Let *f* be a compression algorithm. If compressing `A` and `B` yields the same file, then *f(A) = f(B) = C*, for some *C*. Now, let *f'* be the decompression algorithm. then *f'(f(A)) = f'(C) = f'(f(B))*. Hence, *f'* uncompresses `A.zip` and `B.zip` to the same file.

So, either *f* is a worthless compression algorithm (because it is not a bijection), or `A` and `B` are in fact the same file. (When I say worthless, I mean worthless for lossless compression!)

As for your other question, note that a lossless compression algorithm is by definition *not* as hashing algorithm, since a hashing function *h* maps a domain *A* on a (generally) smaller domain *B*. Hence *h* **cannot** be a bijection, while we just asserted that our lossless compression function *f* **is** a bijection.

Comment: Worthless is a bit strong; lossy (ie, non-bijective) algorithms are used for audio and imagery all the time

Comment: @bdonlan: you're right. I updated the answer to clarify what I mean by 'worthless' :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be obvious:  If the compressed files are identical then how could the decompressor know whether to make A or B out of it??

This doesn't make a useable hash, though, as the length will be variable.

Answer (score 1):

Compression functions are required to be injective, that is, each input maps to a unique output. If this weren't true, how would the algorithm know whether to decompress back to A or B?

Note that this is only true for lossless (data) compression. It's possible to compress 2 images, for instance, and get the same result, but only if the images were very close to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is kinda general, but since you indicate file-based compression algorithms (your pkzip tag for one thing), then no. There is no way two different lossless compression algorithm can produce the same output from different inputs.

However, for lossy compression algorithms, like JPEG, then sure, that's of course a possibility, but then the files would be nearly identical to begin with.

For instance, take a .PNG file, save it as .JPEG, change one pixel to make it 1 degree brighter or darker in one of the channels, resave it as a .JPEG, and you have a chance that you got two identical files, even though the input was different, albeit slightly.

So lossless algorithms, no, that can't happen. For lossy algorithms, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Cryptographic hash functions have a very specific requirement: to make it very difficult to reverse them. Compression, by definition, is easy to invert, so its a very poor choice for a crypto hash.

**EDIT:**

Note that when I say 'by definition' above, I mean by conventional definition. Strictly speaking, MD5, SHA-1, etc could be considered compression algorithms as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible for [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) algorithms (in opposite to [lossless data compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression)). Theoretically they could give the same result for similar(but still different) input data.

Answer (score 0):

For an algorithm to be a decent cryptographic hash, a small localised change in the input should cause a large disperse change in the output. Also, a hash function is a mapping from an arbitrarily sized input to a fixed size output.